# use of random.choice with kivy buttons

Tags: python, kivy

So, I am creating a program with kivy that is dependant on being able to randomly choose a location from an already created dictionary by using buttons. I want the choice to display on the window the button takes you too rather than in the command line. Is there a way to do that? I have attached a snippet of .py code and my kivy code. I want the output displayed on the window (picture also attached) where it says "Go to:"

.py code:

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
FoodPlaces={'Asian': ['joy yee','strings','ramen san','chi cafe']}
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class FoodWindow(Screen):
    def asianBtn(self):
        print(random.choice(FoodPlaces['Asian']))
class AsianWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv=Builder.load_file("picker.kv")


class pickerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=="__main__":
    pickerApp().run()
```

kivy code:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    FoodWindow:
    AsianWindow:
<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:"Pick a Category"
        Button:
            text:"Food"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="food"
                root.manager.transition.direction="left"
<FoodWindow>:
    name: "food"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:"Pick a Food Type"
        Button:
            text: "Asian"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="asian"
                root.manager.transition.direction="left"
                root.asianBtn()
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="main"
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
<AsianWindow>
    name:"asian"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Go to:"
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="food"
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of output do you want to display?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I want to display the text or "string" that my function outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to add an `id` to the `Label`:

```
<AsianWindow>
    name:"asian"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            id: goto   # Use this id to access the Label
            text: "Go to:"
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="food"
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
```

To keep it simpler, put the `asianBtn()` method in the `AsianWindow` class:

```
class AsianWindow(Screen):
    def asianBtn(self):
        self.ids.goto.text = random.choice(FoodPlaces['Asian'])
```

And change its call in the `kv` to:

```
<FoodWindow>:
    name: "food"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:"Pick a Food Type"
        Button:
            text: "Asian"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="asian"
                root.manager.transition.direction="left"
                app.root.current_screen.asianBtn()
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="main"
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
```

With the `asianBtn()` method in the `AsianWindow` class, the path to the `goto` `Label` is simpler and the path to the `asianBtn()` method itself is simpler (since the `current_screen` is the `AsianWindow` at that point).

---

An even simpler way is to just use the `on_enter()` method of `AsianWindow`, so that a random choice is displayed whenever the `AsianWindow` is displayed. to do this, just replace the `asianBtn()` method with an `on_enter()` method:

```
class AsianWindow(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.goto.text = random.choice(FoodPlaces['Asian'])
```

And now you don't even need to call `asianBtn()` from the `Button`:

```
<FoodWindow>:
    name: "food"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text:"Pick a Food Type"
        Button:
            text: "Asian"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="asian"
                root.manager.transition.direction="left"
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="main"
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using `print` which won't help you display within the UI. I'm not 100% sure how/where you want to display, but I would advise you to add a label wherever you want to display the output. You would want this label to have an id property so you can change its text value dynamically to whatever the random function chooses from the dict.

The lable will look something like this in kv:

```
Label:
    id: output
```

And to set its value you need a line like this in the py file:

```
self.ids.output.text = "name of restaurant"
```

Hope this helps!